# How to file US federal income taxes on government bonds where interest has been paid every year

Tags: united-states, income-tax, savings-bonds

My wife has some series EE and series I bonds. These bonds have an option to either pay the tax on interest every year or to defer all the tax until they are sold. She picked the first option and has been paying interest on every year (not sure why, but her dad was doing it so she kept doing it).

However, a few years ago when we went to the bank and sold some of the bonds, the bank reported the interest earned as if it had all been deferred and we ended up getting audited on our taxes. I had to write a letter to the IRS explaining that the tax had been paid annually to sort it out.

This year we sold some more bonds and I would like to avoid the hassle of going through another audit and explanation letter. I thought there was supposed to be some form to declare this interest that we already paid, but I am having trouble locating it. Does anyone know what form and line I should be looking for?

Comment: [Pub 550 section "How to report interest income" item "US savings bond interest previously reported"](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2019_publink100010051)